# Can't render model using CBV using django

Tags: python, django

I am currently learning CBV and using it over function view. However, I have difficulty rendering it.

My template **Post_list.html**

```
{% for post in post_list %}
    <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

and my view

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
```

I want to render it into a loop like I used to do with function view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following in your view.

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post_list'
```

If you don't specify a `context_object_name` it will be `object_list`.

Also, in your template:

```
{% for post in post_list %}
    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have done that but I am still unable to render anything. 

My URL is as follow "path('blog/', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-blog'),"

Comment: Ok so it is not working the way you show me.
If i want to render the loops I have to use {% for post in object_list %} and it does work but I have still no idea why